# Data from joined tables not typecast

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a join query to get the attributes of another table along with the query.

```
city = City.first(:select => "cities.*, states.name as state_name, states.time as state_time"
                  :joins => "LEFT JOIN states on cities.state_id = states.id",
                  :conditions => ["states.name = ?", params[:state]])
```

Here, the problem is that when I get the values from the joined tables like `city.state_time`, I will get the string like `2010-11-12 05:00:00` instead of the time object(no typecasting is done by Rails for these fields). It makes sense since I am calling City model and the methods used for typecasting time column will be in State model. I will have to explicitly parse time like this and will have to fight with the time zone issues as well. (as Rails do some customizations while giving the Time object and I will have to do these for these columns). Is there any way to link the columns to the State while doing the join. One method I thought of was like this.

```
state = State.new(:name => city.state_name, :time => city.state_time)
```

and use `state.name` and `state.time`. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's probably what you want:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
end

class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
end

a = City.joins(:state).includes(:state).where(['states.name = ?', params[:state]]).first
a.state.time
```

This works using an inner join and has some conditions:

- City must belong to only one state. If the city doesn't belong to any state the query won't return it because of the inner join

**Rails 2 Syntax**

```
a = City.find(:all, :conditions => ['states.name = ?', params[:state]], :joins => :state, :include => :state)
```

Comment: The original problem, I am facing is that Rails do a lot by typecasting the strings into objects and for the joined table I have to remember all these and do it in my model. That is why I am initializing the `State` model object but even that is not working as `State.new` is taking Time in the time zone that is defined in the config file.

Comment: hey, I've completely edited my answer. Why did you use a LEFT JOIN by the way?

Comment: ok..thanks..got it..I was working on already existing code and I am not sure why left join was used but I think inner join will be enough..BTW I am trying to find the equivalent in Rails 2 but this will work. I have a question though..will `includes` prevent from firing another sql query while calling `a.state`. I mean in normal case it will fire the query `SELECT * from states where id = #{a.state_id}`?

Comment: Hi, includes triggers eager loading of the association this means a query like `SELECT * FROM states WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4,5)` so it's only one query extra. Check [Ruby on Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations). In Rails 2 you have to place the `:joins` and `:includes` stuff inside the `find(...)`.

Comment: I've added the syntax for Rails 2 (is also compatible with Rails 3)

Comment: This way, I dont have to edit the join query also...I can still pass the `left join` query in the `:joins` key.